# Blade's OR statement always echoing default

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I have a code that was working fine in PHP 5. But I updated my system and now I'm using PHP 7. The problem happens in every Blade code that uses `or` statement and the variable is not directly read from the object. In this situation, Blade always echoes the default value.

For example:

```
{{$obj->customer->state->name or '-'}}
```

Result in PHP 5:

`Santa Catarina`

Result in PHP 7:

`-`

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and all the data stored in DB is the same for both results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{{$obj->customer->state->name ?? '-'}}
```

This is a new feature in PHP 7

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: Hi! This works well. But can you tell me if this is using a Blade statement or a PHP 7 one? I'm asking this because if I need to go back to PHP 5, it will not work.

Comment: Glad it works. This is a PHP 7 feature. I have updated my answer with a reference.

Comment: Ok! So, I'll need to find a way to merge these features in the future, to avoid this version issue. But for now it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, for this I would write a custom blade helper method and detect version using ```phpversion()```. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
{{isset($obj->customer->state->name) ? $obj->customer->state->name : '-'}}
```